# How to stop CSS table row from going offscreen

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xerooz5p/

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:3KiexfmhxHvG5IgAElmTkd">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/1e6c3774deb8c44852ac169e03ce3f7a37c936af" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Please Please Me (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Please Please Me  - 1</span>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:4ekUX4pWizXXksJe0JfS9U">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/1e684af9619d7310229826fab2d6ce490cb954f1" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">With The Beatles (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">With The Beatles  - 3</span>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:5J2CHimS7dWYMImCHkEFaJ">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/56f312139863addd3837e68e6c198150e80f510a" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">A Hard Day&#39;s Night (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">A Hard Day&#39;s Night  - 2</span>                
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:4ltC6PrqkTtpcRNi5lvS4z">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/863e2f879a99e4afb084a6d0eb39ef37e596d5d2" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Beatles For Sale (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Beatles For Sale  - 4</span>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:06ypiqmILMdVeaiErMFA91">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/e26910fd9e7bb1671213cb9ed06a855077ddd79f" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Rubber Soul (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Rubber Soul  - 3</span>               
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:4BRkPBUxOYffM2QXVlq7aC">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/75ef0990aa0bb02ef7f6a52d41cc2c4c8028c3ba" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Revolver (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Revolver  - 4</span>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:0qHMhBZqYb99yhX9BHcIkV">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/5efcba83e06ce03ca843b459a4189f861ddc5f23" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Magical Mystery Tour (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Magical Mystery Tour  - 2</span>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:0j3p1p06deJ7f9xmJ9yG22">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/2782d94528b449fb6910300cc8c8f93ab8cc7a8d" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">The Beatles (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">The Beatles  - 5</span>               
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cellForAlbum">

            <a href="spotify:track:0CaBBQsaAiRHhiLmzi7ZRp">
                <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/b3651a85f2bca826b38194c51d09cd7b068aa3ab" alt="" />
            </a>

            <div class="albumName">
                <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
                <div style="display:none;">Let It Be (Remastered)</div>
                <span class="caption">Let It Be  - 2</span>             
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Right now the width of the table row is getting set by the amount of cells that are in there. So the width is something like 1600 and it goes off screen and I have to horizontally scroll to see them. Is there a way to stop this so it doesn't go past the width of my monitor?

Comment: Have you thought about using twitter bootstrap grids? It would make your life easier.

Comment: maybe so? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/11mjLcqw/

Answer (score 0):

maybe `table-layout` is what you look for and eventually `max-width` for img:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cellForArtistName {
  display: table-cell;
}
.cellForAlbum {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
.artistName {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.albumName {
  /*width: 175px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellForArtistName">
      <p class="artistName">The Beatles</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:3KiexfmhxHvG5IgAElmTkd">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/1e6c3774deb8c44852ac169e03ce3f7a37c936af" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Please Please Me (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Please Please Me  - 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:4ekUX4pWizXXksJe0JfS9U">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/1e684af9619d7310229826fab2d6ce490cb954f1" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">With The Beatles (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">With The Beatles  - 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:5J2CHimS7dWYMImCHkEFaJ">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/56f312139863addd3837e68e6c198150e80f510a" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">A Hard Day&#39;s Night (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">A Hard Day&#39;s Night  - 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:4ltC6PrqkTtpcRNi5lvS4z">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/863e2f879a99e4afb084a6d0eb39ef37e596d5d2" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Beatles For Sale (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Beatles For Sale  - 4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:06ypiqmILMdVeaiErMFA91">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/e26910fd9e7bb1671213cb9ed06a855077ddd79f" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Rubber Soul (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Rubber Soul  - 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:4BRkPBUxOYffM2QXVlq7aC">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/75ef0990aa0bb02ef7f6a52d41cc2c4c8028c3ba" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Revolver (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Revolver  - 4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:0qHMhBZqYb99yhX9BHcIkV">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/5efcba83e06ce03ca843b459a4189f861ddc5f23" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Magical Mystery Tour (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Magical Mystery Tour  - 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:0j3p1p06deJ7f9xmJ9yG22">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/2782d94528b449fb6910300cc8c8f93ab8cc7a8d" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">The Beatles (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">The Beatles  - 5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellForAlbum">
      <a href="spotify:track:0CaBBQsaAiRHhiLmzi7ZRp">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/b3651a85f2bca826b38194c51d09cd7b068aa3ab" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="albumName">
        <!-- the below hidden div has the album name that gets sent to the server onclick of this albumName div -->
        <div style="display:none;">Let It Be (Remastered)</div>
        <span class="caption">Let It Be  - 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```